# Динамичный @Query в Retrofit

Tags: retrofit2

Написал я, значит, так:

```
@POST("login/?wicket:interface=:{wicket}:loginForm:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::")
Call<Document> auth(@Path("wicket") long wicket, @FieldMap HashMap<String, String> postData);
```

POST запрос с передачей Query и Field одновременно. Думал, `@Path` будет заменять в ссылке значение `{wicket}`, но нет:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "wicket:interface=:{wicket}:loginForm:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Тут всего один `Query` параметр: `wicket:interface` со значением `:{wicket}:loginForm:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::`.

Как мне создать динамичное `@Query` значение так чтобы в метод `auth` нужно было передать только `wicket`? (ну и `@FieldMap`, с ним все хорошо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Retrofit` не подходит в этом случае. Хоть он и имеет крутые аннотации, функционал из-за этого жестко урезан. Полностью все контролировать можно, например, с `FastAndroidNetworking`